# Performing a getattr() style lookup in a django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Python's `getattr()` method is useful when you don't know the name of a certain attribute in advance.

This functionality would also come in handy in templates, but I've never figured out a way to do it. Is there a built-in tag or non-built-in tag that can perform dynamic attribute lookups?

Comment: I wonder if you are trying to do too much in your templates. getattr sometimes feels like black magic in Python code so it's surely a code smell in a template!

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I also had to write this code as a custom template tag recently. To handle all look-up scenarios, it first does a standard attribute look-up, then tries to do a dictionary look-up, then tries a **getitem** lookup (for lists to work), then follows standard Django template behavior when an object is not found.

(updated 2009-08-26 to now handle list index lookups as well)

```
# app/templatetags/getattribute.py

import re
from django import template
from django.conf import settings

numeric_test = re.compile("^\d+$")
register = template.Library()

def getattribute(value, arg):
    """Gets an attribute of an object dynamically from a string name"""

    if hasattr(value, str(arg)):
        return getattr(value, arg)
    elif hasattr(value, 'has_key') and value.has_key(arg):
        return value[arg]
    elif numeric_test.match(str(arg)) and len(value) > int(arg):
        return value[int(arg)]
    else:
        return settings.TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID

register.filter('getattribute', getattribute)
```

Template usage:

```
{% load getattribute %}
{{ object|getattribute:dynamic_string_var }}
```

Comment: I'm missing something here -- what's the purpose of the second and third clauses? If `hasattr(value, 'has_key')`, then can't you access it in a template using `value.arg`? Similarly if it's an array, `value.i` gets the i'th element. Are these just so the function handles these redundant cases?

Comment: Those exist as convenience to mimic the behavior Django templates—when you do `{{value.arg}}`, Django checks if it is attribute of the object (clause 1), a dictionary key (clause 2), a list index (clause 3), and then falls through to a blank string by default. So yes, `{{value|getattribute:dynamic_arg_name}}` is not "getattribute" in the purest Python sense, but it does behave the same way as normal Django lookups.

Comment: You should use ``str.isdigit`` instead of ``numeric_test = re.compile("^\d+$")``: ``timeit r.match('1'): 306 ns`` and ``timeit '1'.isdigit() 47.6 ns``.

Comment: And do not use ``dict.has_key``, it has been removed in Python 3.x, use ``in`` instead.

Comment: I would also do a "callable" check on the result and call it if is callable so you don't get method names being displayed.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so.  But it wouldn't be too hard to write a [custom template tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) to return an attribute in the context dict.  If you're simply trying to return a string, try something like this:

```
class GetAttrNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, attr_name):
        self.attr_name = attr_name

    def render(self, context):
        try:
            return context[self.attr_name]
        except:
            # (better yet, return an exception here)
            return ''

@register.tag
def get_attr(parser, token):
    return GetAttrNode(token)
```

Note that it's probably just as easy to do this in your view instead of in the template, unless this is a condition that is repeated often in your data.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up adding a method to the model in question, and that method can be accessed like an attribute in the template.

Still, i think it would be great if a built in tag allowed you to dynamically lookup an attribute, since this is a problem a lot of us constantly have in our templates.

Answer (score 2):

Keeping the distinction between get and getattr,

```
@register.filter(name='get')
def get(o, index):
    try:
        return o[index]
    except:
        return settings.TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID


@register.filter(name='getattr')
def getattrfilter(o, attr):
    try:
        return getattr(o, attr)
    except:
        return settings.TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID
```

Answer (score 1):

That snippet saved my day but i needed it to span it over relations so I changed it to split the arg by "." and recursively get the value.
It could be done in one line:
`return getattribute(getattribute(value,str(arg).split(".")[0]),".".join(str(arg).split(".")[1:]))`
but I left it in 4 for readability.
I hope someone has use for this.

```
import re
from django import template
from django.conf import settings

numeric_test = re.compile("^\d+$")
register = template.Library()

def getattribute(value, arg):
"""Gets an attribute of an object dynamically AND recursively from a string name"""
    if "." in str(arg):
        firstarg = str(arg).split(".")[0]
        value = getattribute(value,firstarg)
        arg = ".".join(str(arg).split(".")[1:])
        return getattribute(value,arg)
    if hasattr(value, str(arg)):
        return getattr(value, arg)
    elif hasattr(value, 'has_key') and value.has_key(arg):
        return value[arg]
    elif numeric_test.match(str(arg)) and len(value) > int(arg):
        return value[int(arg)]
    else:
        #return settings.TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID
        return 'no attr.' + str(arg) + 'for:' + str(value)

register.filter('getattribute', getattribute)
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built-in tag, but it shouldn't be too difficult to [write your own](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#howto-custom-template-tags).

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a more generic solution based on @fotinakis solution, it serves to find the value of a string expression whether it is an attribute or a function, and also supports objects chaining.

```
import re
import types

numeric_test = re.compile("^\d+$")
register = template.Library()

def get_attr(object, arg):
    if hasattr(object, str(arg)):
        attr = getattr(object, arg)
        if type(getattr(object, str(arg))) == types.MethodType:
            return attr()
        return attr
    elif hasattr(object, 'has_key') and object.has_key(arg):
        return object[arg]
    elif numeric_test.match(str(arg)) and len(object) > int(arg):
        return object[int(arg)]
    else:
        return object


@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def get_by_name(context, name):
    """"Get variable by string name {% get_by_name data_name.data_func... %}"""
    print(context['instance'].get_edit_url())
    arr = name.split('.')
    obj = arr[0]
    object = context[obj]
    if len(arr) > 1:
        for ar in arr:
            object = get_attr(object, ar)
    return object
```