# Access a model's field by another field's value in a template in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates

I don't really know how to describe what I'm aiming at (EDIT: I want a dynamic attribute lookup), but I'm trying to do something like this
`<p>{{dict.{{object.field}}}}</p>` in a template. I also tried:

```
{% with object.field as field %}
     {{dict.field}}
{% endwith %}
```

which didn't work either. Do you know how to tackle this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844746/performing-a-getattr-style-lookup-in-a-django-template).

Answer (score 0):

To loop through a dictionary you use "for":

```
{% for dictionary.object as obj %}
    {{ obj.field }}
{% endfor %}
```