# Iterating through Expando's Dynamic properties in Django Templates

Tags: python, google-app-engine, templates, iteration, expando

I'm trying to iterate through an Expando-Model's dynamic properties in order to output them all. Is there a way of doing this other than creating your own method like such:

```
class Event(db.Expando):
    platform = db.ReferenceProperty(Platform)
    date = db.DateTimeProperty()

    def getValues(self):
        return self._dynamic_properties
```

And then in the template - which is passed a 'platform' object:

```
{% for event in platform.event_set %}
    <b>{{ event.date }}</b><br />
    {% for pair in event.getValues.items %}
        {{ pair.0 }} = {{ pair.1 }}<br />
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This works, but I'm suprised I can't just do:

```
{% for event in platform.event_set %}
    <b>{{ event.date }}</b><br />
    {% for pair in event.items %}
        {{ pair.0 }} = {{ pair.1 }}<br />
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Without having my own method call... should I use something other than '.items'?

Comment: Does {% for pair in event._dynamic_properties.items %} not work?

Comment: No; there was someone who suggested that but the answer has been withdrawn. It's not possible to access properties that start with an underscore. Cheers for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a db.Model's 'dynamic_properties' method to retrieve an Expando's properties, in the same format as the 'properties' method (as documented [under the Model class](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model_properties))

Remember that those functions don't return a property's value, though... 'properties' returns a dictionary of property names mapped to their implementation class (db.ReferenceProperty and db.DateTimeProperty, in this case), and 'dynamic_properties' simply returns a list of property names, since Expandos can't map a dynamic value to an implementation class.

In order to get the property's value, you have to use `getattr(model, prop_name)`. There is no way to run this function purely inside a Django template (without a [custom tag library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844746/performing-a-getattr-style-lookup-in-a-django-template)), but you could keep and re-write your method like so...

```
def getExpandoValues(self):
   return dict((name, getattr(self, name)) for name, impl_class in self.dynamic_properties())
```

... and re-write your template to access the values via the new dictionary input:

```
{% for event in platform.event_set %}
  <b>{{ event.date }}</b><br />
  {% for pair in event.getExpandoValues %}
     {{ pair.0 }} = {{ pair.1 }}<br />
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```