# Django : Listing model field names and values in template

Tags: python, django, django-models

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Django - Iterate over model instance field names and values in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170228/django-iterate-over-model-instance-field-names-and-values-in-template)

Hi,

I'm trying to list fields and corresponding values of generic Django models in the templates. However I can't find an inbuilt solution for a fairly common problem. I'm pretty close to the solution but can't find a way out.

view.py Code:

```
def showdetails(request, template):
    objects = newivr1_model.objects.all()
    fields = newivr1_model._meta.get_all_field_names()
    return render_to_response(template, {'fields': fields,'objects':objects},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

template code:

```
    <table>                                                                                                                                       
    {% for object in objects %}                                                 
        <tr>                                                                    
            {% for field in fields %}                                           
                <td>                                                            
            <!--    {{ object.field }} /*This line doesn't work*/ -->                                           
                </td>                                                           
            {% endfor %}                                                        
        </tr>                                                                   
    {% endfor %}                                                                
    </table>
```

What should I be doing at the commented template line so that i get the value of Object.field?

Any better DRY methods are most welcome as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do lookups like that in the template engine.

You'll have to deal with that in the view.

```
def showdetails(request, template):
    objects = newivr1_model.objects.all()

    for object in objects:
        object.fields = dict((field.name, field.value_to_string(object))
                                            for field in object._meta.fields)

   return render_to_response(template, { 'objects':objects },
                                    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

#### Template

```
{% for object in objects %}
    <tr>
    {% for field, value in object.fields.iteritems %}
        <td>{{ field }} : {{ value }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Not sure if I did something wrong, I got an error `'Model' object is not iterable`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create your own filter, that will work like getattr in python and use it in the template:

```
{{ object|getattribute:field }}
```

Here there is description how to do that: [Performing a getattr() style lookup in a django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844746/performing-a-getattr-style-lookup-in-a-django-template)

But I don't think that's really a good idea. Insted try to do this logic in the view, like this:

```
object_values = []
for object in objects
   object_values.append([])
   for field in fields:
       object_values[-1].append(getattr(object, field))
return render_to_response(template, {'object_values': object_values},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and in the template:

```
<table>                                                                                                                                       
{% for values in object_values %}                                                 
    <tr>                                                                    
        {% for value in values %}                                           
            <td>                                                            
                {{ value }}
            </td>                                                           
        {% endfor %}                                                        
    </tr>                                                                   
{% endfor %}                                                                
</table>
```

Django template system doesn't provide many function (filters), because you are supposed to do all the logic in the views. Template should only present data.

Comment: gruszczy - I'm only trying to present data in templates :) . And in theory this should be a fairly simple and common problem too.

Comment: Then using getattr filter should help you. I believe it is a common problem.