# Return label on the template using ListView

Tags: django, listview, django-templates

We normally do the following command to return a list of items.

```
{% for occupation in occupation_list %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ occupation.occupation }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

My question is: How do I return the name of the fields?

Something like:

```
{% for occupation in fields %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ occupation.occupation_label }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django : Listing model field names and values in template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358800/django-listing-model-field-names-and-values-in-template)

Comment: just check the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually

Comment: Rendering fields with ListView?

Comment: @ruddra Yes, i use ListView.