# Boolean comparison in django template

Tags: django

I have a boolean field in my Django model like

```
reminder = models.BooleanField()
```

Now I want to compare this field in my django template in some certain conditions .

I am doing like this

```
{% if x.reminder == 'True' %}
```

But unfortunately above code is not giving me expected result .I want to remove all `reminder = False`  Please help me what might I am doing wrong here .

Comment: Wouldn't this be sufficient `{% if x.reminder %}`?

Comment: What you are doing is comparing the boolean reminder to a string value 'True'

Comment: Actually I was derailed  but now go tthe solution

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you are comparing `x.reminder` to a string named `'True'`, not the True constant

```
{% if x.reminder %}
```

or

```
{% if x.reminder == True %}
```

Answer (score 6):

Just use this:

```
{% if x.reminder %}
```

This (without quotes) works since django 1.5, but it's superfluous.

```
{% if x.reminder == True %}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/#minor-features

> The template engine now interprets True, False and None as the corresponding Python objects.