# Django use value of template variable as part of another variable name

Tags: python, django, variables, django-templates

I currently have this for loop inside my template:

```
{% for i in 1234|make_list %}
```

I would like to obtain something like this inside loop:

```
{{ form.answer_{{ i }} }}
```

I am aware that the above line is not valid (it raises TemplateSyntaxError), but I would like to know if there is any way to use the value of i as part my other variable name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you would need a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) to mimic [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) functionality, see:

- [Performing a getattr() style lookup in a django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844746/performing-a-getattr-style-lookup-in-a-django-template)

Then, you would need [`add` template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#add) for string concatenation:

```
{% load getattribute %}

{% for i in 1234|make_list %}    
    {% with "answer_"|add:i as answer %}
        {{ form|getattribute:answer }}
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```