# django form dynamic attribute lookup

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm facing an issue, and can't figure out how to solve it.

I have the following form in my application:

```
class ContentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Content
        fields = ('url_1','url_2','url_3','url_4','url_5',)
        widgets = {
            'url_1': forms.URLInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'maxlength': 100}),
            'url_2': forms.URLInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'maxlength': 100}),
            'url_3': forms.URLInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'maxlength': 100}),
            'url_4': forms.URLInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'maxlength': 100}),
            'url_5': forms.URLInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'maxlength': 100}),
        }
```

What I'm trying to do is to generate those url fields dynamically through a loop. I took [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27324602/django-use-value-of-template-variable-as-part-of-another-variable-name/27324674#27324674) approach (which implements a template tag for dynamic attribute lookup):

```
{% for i in 12345|make_list %}
    {% with url='url_'|add:i %}
      {{ form|getattribute:url }}
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

However it's not working. Django doesn't render the input field and complains that my form object doesn't have an attribute called `url_1` for example. If I call the `url_1` attribute for the same form directly it works.

The implementation of the `getattribute` template tag is the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844746/performing-a-getattr-style-lookup-in-a-django-template).

**[UPDATE: posted my code below]**

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def new(request):
    form = ContentForm()
    return render(request, "new.html", {'form': form})
```

**new.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'create_content' %}" method="POST">
...
{% include 'partials/urls.html' %}
...
</form>
```

**urls.html**

```
{% load getattribute %}

{% for i in 12345|make_list %}
    {% with url='url_'|add:i %}
      <label>URL {{i}}</label>
      {{ form|getattribute:url }}
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

**getattribute.py**

```
import re
from django import template
from django.conf import settings

numeric_test = re.compile("^\d+$")
register = template.Library()

def getattribute(value, arg):
        """Gets an attribute of an object dynamically from a string name"""

        return getattr(value, arg)

    if hasattr(value, str(arg)):
        return getattr(value, arg)
    elif hasattr(value, 'has_key') and value.has_key(arg):
        return value[arg]
    elif numeric_test.match(str(arg)) and len(value) > int(arg):
        return value[int(arg)]
    else:
        return settings.TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID

register.filter('getattribute', getattribute)
```

ps.: django version running is 1.9.2

Comment: python version 2.7.10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the `getattribute.py` as below:

```
import re
from django.forms import Form, ModelForm
from django import template
from django.conf import settings

numeric_test = re.compile("^\d+$")
register = template.Library()

def getattribute(value, arg):
    """Gets an attribute of an object dynamically from a string name"""
    if hasattr(value, str(arg)):
        return getattr(value, arg)
    elif hasattr(value, 'has_key') and value.has_key(arg):
        return value[arg]
    elif numeric_test.match(str(arg)) and len(value) > int(arg):
        return value[int(arg)]
    elif issubclass(value.__class__, (Form, ModelForm)) and arg in value.fields:
        return value[arg]
    else:
        return settings.TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID

register.filter('getattribute', getattribute)
```

You can see in 17th and 18th lines that expected for special condition, related to forms and returned related rendered widget ;)

Comment: You shouldn't need to add special checks for forms. The `has_key` check will work for Python 2 (it should be changed for Python 3).

Comment: The `has_key` method do samething as `arg in value.fields`, thanks @Alasdair

Comment: Your saying is correct, but keys in `value` is equal to `value.fields`... i change it only for you :)

Comment: after changing my code, cant see fields...
Current code is usable

Comment: Mohsen GREAT!!!! It worked changing the subclass verification upon `ModelForm` instead of `Form`. Thanks a lot.

ps: I still don't get why the `getattr` approach didn't worked as they are the same object.
ps2: I'm wondering why I didn't try it before :P

Comment: @Mohsen my mistake, it looks like the `has_key` check returns False for Django forms. I think the best solution might be to replace the `has_key` check with `return value[arg]`, and catch the possible `KeyError`. Then you don't have special code for the `Form` class.

Comment: The `getattr` function return value of a **property** but in forms field-name using as key and you must check key existing status by `in` keyword

Comment: @Alasdair however your suggest not worked in this case, but we learned a new trick, thanks very much.