# Nested for loop in django template for variables

Tags: django, django-templates

```
 <tbody>
        {% for j in dat %}
        <tr>
            {%for h in hed %}
            <td>{{j.h}}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
```

want to get value by object.field_name from the model. I've tried {{ j }}.{{ h }} but it does not return the value instead returns obj1.field_name. Any possible method i should try.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Performing a getattr() style lookup in a django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844746/performing-a-getattr-style-lookup-in-a-django-template)

Comment: tried the getattribute() template tag and it returned AttributeError: 
'Settings' object has no attribute 'TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID'. Should i alter the settings.py file?

Comment: You can replace `TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID` with any sting you want. It does not matter in your case

Comment: Thanks to you , worked finally!