# Dynamically render matrix like form in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am using a Django model to represent day-hour combinations. The goal is to render a matrix-like form with the days on the x-axis and the hours on the y-axis. The user can check each combination to define when a vehicle is available during a week.

The model looks as follows:

```
class TimeMatrix(models.Model):
    MO00 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    MO01 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    MO02 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    MO03 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ....
    SO22 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    SO23 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I like to render the corresponding form coming from the CreateView as the mentioned matrix. The html to do this requires a list of `days = ['MON', 'TUE', ..., 'SUN']` and `hours = ['00', '01', ..., '23']` in order to render the form dynamically. The following html shows this *without* using the form the Django `CreateView` provides:

```
<form action="#">
    <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
            <thead class="thead-light">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Day</th>
                    {% for h in hours %}
                    <th scope="col">{{h}}</th>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for d in days %}
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row" class="wt-col">{{d}}</th>
                    {% for h in hours %}
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="{{d}}{{h}}" value="{{d}}{{h}}" id="id_{{d}}{{h}}"></td>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

Since I like to use the security measures build into Django forms I like this to make use of the `form` the `CreateView` provides. Following [this](https://www.webforefront.com/django/formtemplatelayout.html) explanation, the individual form can be accessed using `form.<field_name>`. Combining this with the html would require a dynamic way to access the form fields, which for me raises two questions:

1. Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844746/performing-a-getattr-style-lookup-in-a-django-template) advice I was able to implement getattr functionality for the templates which works with my models, but fails on the `form` the CreateView provides (e.g. `{{form|getattribute:'MON00'}}`). What am I missing?
2. Since I cannot concat the day and hour string in the template (`{{form|getattribute:d+h}}` will not work), what is a suitable way to access the required form field?

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not. For now it does not use the provided form but rather creates the object from scratch after receiving the POST.