# How to access to dictionary value via variables in another list in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

I have this situation in my views.py

```
d = {'05:45':3,'06:30':6 (...) }
T = ['05:45','06:30' (...)]
```

I would like to get `d[T[i]]` in my HTML site

I tried to call this with dot, but it doesn't work. I will be thankful for help/hint.

Comment: "I tried to call this with dot, but it doesn't work." What did you try *exactly*? And how did it not work, *exactly*?

Comment: I tried {{ d.{{T.i}} }}, I get an error Could not parse the remainder

Answer (score 0):

Thing you are trying to do is to get element from dictionary using variable. Am I right ? In django template engine it's a little bit tricky, but possible. Use some template tag from this question to acomplish this

[Performing a getattr() style lookup in a django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844746/performing-a-getattr-style-lookup-in-a-django-template)

Comment: meh I read about this method, but this is so complicated for me.(I just begin my adventure with Django)