# Accessing session variable based on variable in for loop django template

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates, session-variables

I have some products listed which can be in a cart, this cart is stored in a session variable dictionary for which the key is the product id and the value is some information about the quantity and stuff. I want to add the option to view (on the products page) how many of that product are in your cart.

I know I can access session variables in a django template like this:

```
{{ request.session.cart.2323.quantity }}
```

Problem is, the key (2323 in this case) is a variable which depends on a `for` loop:

```
{% for prod in products %}
  <p>{{ request.session.cart[prod.name].quantity }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

But implementing it like that unfortunately is not possible. Is there any way in which this would be possible or would I have to change the way my cart works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement a custom template filter like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1112236/17556172) to have the ability to use [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr).

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_object_property_dinamically(your_object, first_property, second_property):
    return getattr(getattr(your_object, first_property), second_property)
```

```
{% load get_object_property_dinamically %}
{% for prod in products %}
  <p>{% multiple_args_tag request.session.cart prod.name 'quantity' %}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, in the end I did not use the `getattr` but instead just `your object[first_property][second_property]`, the first did not work.